# How to correctly access v2.0 of REST API in PowerShell for mailbox management

Tags: powershell, outlook-restapi

We have a PowerShell script which checks a service mailbox and updates our wallboards with information, then moves the relevant emails to the deleted folder. This was set up under API v1.0 which is now deprecated and we're needing to get it changed for version 2.0.

Unfortunately, this has led to a lot of confusion and a lot of scratched heads which isn't too fun. This has occurred mainly around getting an oAuth2 token then feeding it into the request for the mailbox.

So far, we've managed to get the Azure AD app registered and it's providing an authentication token, but that's coming back as unauthorised from Microsoft Graph.

```
# tenantID, clientSecret and clientID not here.

# The resource URI
$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
# Your Client ID and Client Secret obainted when registering your WebApp

$redirectUri = "http://returnuri"

# UrlEncode the ClientID and ClientSecret and URL's for special characters 
$clientIDEncoded = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($ClientID)
$clientSecretEncoded = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($clientSecret)
$redirectUriEncoded =  [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($redirectUri)
$resourceEncoded = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($resource)
$scopeEncoded = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("https://outlook.office.com/user.readwrite.all")

$body = @"
client_id=$ClientID
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=$clientSecretEncoded
&grant_type=client_credentials
"@

$userid = 'userID'

$accessToken = Invoke-RestMethod "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method Post -Body $body
#
#$cred = $(Get-Credential)

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$userid/messages" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($accessToken.access_token)"} -Credential $cred
```

Expected results: access to the mailbox.

Actual results:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At line:32 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$useri ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation:     (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint on `$accessToken` and check if its there ?

Comment: It is probably a rights thing. Have you granted the rights with an administrator account? You can do so by assigning the rights in Microsoft Graph app and then login to the office admin portal with the administrator account. You will then be asked to accept the requested permissions.

Comment: @HariHaran We did put a breakpoint in and the token is definitely there.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers We need to access a mailbox which is what the creds are for. We've got the permissions set for the token but it's accessing a service account. So I assume the creds are necessary.. (at least that's what I'm told by one of my colleagues)